# not getting output on submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```js
function display()
        {
            var projectorCost=0,price=0,quantity=0,discountPrice=0,totalCost=0;
            var modelName=document.getElementById('projectormodel').value;
            var quantity=document.getElementById('quantity').value;
            var couponCode=document.getElementById('couponcode').value;
            var res=document.getElementById('result');
            if(modelname=='Mobile Portable Projector')
            {
                price=30000;
                if(couponCode=='EveryCam45P'){
                    projectorCost=quantity*price;
                    discountPrice=projectorCost*0.1;
                    totalCost=projectorCost-discountPrice;
                   
                }
                else if(couponCode='EveryCam48P'){
                    projectorCost=quantity*price;
                    discountPrice=projectorCost*0.15;
                    totalCost=projectorCost-discountPrice;
                    
                }  
            }
            if(modelName=='Lumen DLP Projector'){
                price=31000;
                if(couponCode='EveryCam45P'){
                    projectorCost=quantity*price;
                    discountPrice=projectorCost*0.1;
                    totalCost=projectorCost-discountPrice;
                    
                }
                else if(couponCode='EveryCam48P'){
                    projectorCost=quantity*price;
                    discountPrice=projectorCost*0.15;
                    totalCost=projectorCost-discountPrice;
                    
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("res").innerHTML='Your order is successfully placed and you need to pay Rs.'+totalCost;
            return false;
        }
```

My html and CSS is fine but issue is with js code
on submitting the form its not printing the inner HTML of result id
I think I have written javascript in wrong way
Please guide me as i am the beginner in this language

Comment: Please add some HTML to begin with

Comment: We need to see the related HTML, and whatever triggers the `display()` function.  Also, is the function being triggered?  And if so, are the values you're calculating in the function giving you the results you expect?

Comment: Also you should parse the quantity variables to numbers. A input returns a string not a number. When you do math to these variables, the value are being treated as a string.

Comment: One problem:  You're triggering your function on submit but not preventing the default action of a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is problem `var res=document.getElementById('result');`
it should be `var res=document.getElementById('result').value;`
if you   want the value.if you  want inner HTML
`var res=document.getElementById('result').innerHTML` otherwise add your HTML file for Better understanding

Comment: @devlin carnate i have added html because on editing on question it says too much lines of code. Please allow me to post html here